# module 'accounts.views' has no attribute 'signup'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
File "/Users/work/Projects/blog/myblog/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('post/<int:pk>/signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
AttributeError: module 'accounts.views' has no attribute 'signup'
```

I am trying to do a registration by mail using this guide https://shafikshaon.medium.com/user-registration-with-email-verification-in-django-8aeff5ce498d

**myblog/views.py**

```
import json
from urllib import request

from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode

UserModel = get_user_model()
from .forms import SignUpForm
from .tokens import account_activation_token


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        # print(form.errors.as_data())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'post_comment.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    #fields = '__all__'

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic


class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

**myblog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts import views

from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
    BlogUpdateView,
    BlogDeleteView,
    BlogCommentView,

)

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', BlogCommentView.as_view(), name='post_comment'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),

    path('post/<int:pk>/signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),

]
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('myblog.urls')),


]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username')
```

Since I'm new to django, it is possible that I inserted some code in the wrong place

I want the question to be as clear as possible to solve the problem, but I don’t know how to do it, since I don’t understand everything in the code, so I ask you to write any advice, if you need to throw something else, tell me and I’ll throw it off

p.s.
*user_registration* = my *blog*

*accounts* = my *myblog*

my *accounts/views.py* - it is a separate folder with migrations and files

I don't know, maybe the **views.py** code from the guide needs to be inserted not into **myblog/views.py**, but into **accounts.py**, since "signup" and "active"are highlighted in **myblog/urls.py** and a message appears that you need to create these functions in **accounts/view.py**, in general, I'm confused, this is probably a useless question, if everything is too difficult, please direct me in the other direction, how can I try to register by mail, mb for some video tutorial or another guide, thanks a lot

Comment: The views `signup` and `activate` are declared in `myblog.views` yet you are trying to access them from `accounts.views` (In your url patterns `path('post/<int:pk>/signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),` and the one below it)

Comment: I do not quite understand you, what is where and how do I need to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

SignUpView in accounts.views in a class based view not a function based View, so it be mentioned in a different way

```
path('post/<int:pk>/signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup")
```

Comment: As I understand it, I need a signup from **myblog/views.py**, and not from **accounts/views.py**, how can this be done in urls?

Comment: This can be the issue path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to your myblog/urls.py file

```
from .views import signup
```

Comment: this line gets the color as "unused"